# Generating Lists of Primitive Pythagorean Triples in Python

Tags: python, function, math

[Improving a closed question] I've seen a lot of questions that ask very similar questions, but I haven't been able to find a sufficient answer which involves this Euclidean formula. I want to try and create a formula that generates a list of all Pythagorean Triples up to a given number, say k. A pythagorean triple is (x,y,z) where x^2 + y^2 = z^2. It should meet the condition such that x<y<z<k

I originally used a triple nested loop that ran through the iterative ranges of x,y,z checking whether the conditions were met, but this is not efficient. So instead, I want to use the fact that Euclid proved that every primitive Pythagorean triple arises as:

(m^2 − n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2)

where m, n are coprime integers which are not both odd. Coprime integers are a pair of numbers that do not share any common factors other than 1. So this can easily be checked using the math.gcd function. Furthermore we can check that two integers are not odd using mod(2) easily enough. But from here I'm unsure how this would be coded, how could I run through these conditions and generate a list of Pythagorean triples efficiently?

This is my first attempt at the code, but it doesn't work. I believe it should return the triplets:
(3, 4,5), (5, 12, 13), (8, 15, 17).

```
def primpythtrips(k):
    result = []
    for m in (1,k+1):
        for n in (2,k):
            if m%2 != 0 and n%2 != 0:
                break
            elif gcd(m, n) == 1:
                result.append(m*m-n*n)
                result.append(2*m*n)
                result.append(n*m+n*n)
    return result

primpythtrips(20)
Out[9]: [-3, 4, 6, -399, 40, 420, 437, 84, 46, 41, 840, 820]
```

Where have I gone wrong here? Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: You're repeatedly appending to a single list, so why do you expect this to return 3 tuples?

Comment: What's the function `gcd()`? (Just googled it) is that the math.gcd() function?

Comment: @JeffUK I tried appending three arguments but the function doesn't facilitate this. Hence why I tried that. Not saying the code is anywhere near perfect

Comment: @ThomasKimber Yes from the math module. It finds the greatest common divisor between two numbers

Comment: The error is on `result.append(n*m+n*n)` it should be `result.append(m*m+n*n)`.  Also, you should build you result as tuples: `result.append((m*m-n*n,2*m*n,m*m+n*n))` rather than appending 3 individual values.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this as an generator that will produce triples up to z < k:

```
from math import gcd

def genTriples(k):
    n,m = 1,2
    while m*m+1<k:                  # while z<k (for largest m producing z)
        if n>=m: n,m = m%2,m+1      # n reached m, advance m, reset n
        z = m*m+n*n                 # compute z 
        if z >= k: n=m;continue     # skip remaining n when z >= k
        if gcd(n,m) == 1:           # trigger on coprimes
            yield m*m-n*n,2*m*n,z   # return x,y,z triple
        n += 2                      # advance n, odds with evens
```

output:

```
for x,y,z in genTriples(100): print(x,y,z)

3 4 5
5 12 13
15 8 17
7 24 25
21 20 29
9 40 41
35 12 37
11 60 61
45 28 53
33 56 65
13 84 85
63 16 65
55 48 73
39 80 89
77 36 85
65 72 97
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
def pythagore_triplets(n=20):
    res=[] 
    maxn=int(n*(2**0.5))+1 # max int whose square may be the sum of two squares
    squares=[x*x for x in range(maxn+1)] # calculate all the squares once
    reverse_squares=dict([(squares[i],i) for i in range(maxn+1)]) # x*x=>x
    for x in range(1,n):
        x2 = squares[x]
        for y in range(x,n+1):
            y2 = squares[y]
            z = reverse_squares.get(x2+y2)
            if z != None:
                res.append([x,y,z])
    return res

print(pythagore_triplets())
```

Comment: Sorry this won't suffice as I'm trying to use Euclids formula to make the code as efficient as possible. Thanks for the answwer though.